# Adding new columns to an existing sqlite table vs adding a new table

Tags: sqlite, relational-database

In Sqlite3, is there a significant performance difference between adding `n` columns to an existing table versus adding a new table with `n` columns?  And what about deleting `n` columns from a table versus dropping a full table of `n` columns?

Comment: What did you measure?

Comment: Nothing yet honestly. Mostly wondering if someone who understands the implementation of Sqlite knows of any details or optimizations that might cause these two actions to differ in performance.

Comment: You can't drop columns from a SQLite table. [SQLite supports a limited subset of ALTER TABLE. The ALTER TABLE command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table or to add a new column to an existing table.](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)